# How do I wire an old furnace motor so I can use it as a garage exhaust fan?

Tags: electrical, hvac, garage, furnace, blower

Since last I posted, I moved WAY south (lil warm down here) and the house I moved into was a foreclosure so a few things needed done, namely the AC and furnace.  When the guy did the job he said he would (did?) leave the old motor behind so I could use it for some airflow in the garage.  Here's what it looks like...

[image: big huge honkin' fan]

Onto my real questions -- I don't have the wiring diagram, but if I had to guess, I'd say that plug is a speed control (black the common?), and the white is the hookup.  Is that right?  And 
 has anyone rigged one of these up and if so, how'd you do it?

==== updated 7/1/2012 ====

I got motivated today and started to clean it and look for tags that might help identify what it is -- and well, I think this answers everything (and I got a good picture of it!).  It's a Westinghouse 323P683 1/4 hp, 115v motor so xcythe you we're close on those wires (much better than my guess).

[image: Westinghouse 323 P 683, 3 speed 1/4 hp motor]

If I'm reading this correctly...

White-Red : low speed
White-Blue : medium
White-Black : high

Comment: What does the white sticker with the circles say? That looks like a little pin out diagram

Comment: Do you know the make and model of the furnace?  You might be able to find a schematic online if you do.

Answer (score 4):

Squirrel cage blowers make great fans. Black is ground, white-negative and red-positive. Looks like blue, white and red coming from the motor. Read the info on the motor, it should have split capacitor in it, may have to change the wiring from 220 to 110. Looks like a 1/4-1/5 horse. Ask a local HVAC guy, feed his ego and be rewarded. If its a 110 just throw a three prong on it and breeze away. I pulled some romex off the coil and pulled a spare heavy duty three prong outta my tool bucket and had a great workshop fan w/ a super long cord.(put a triangle shaped piece of plywood on one side to stabilize it, and a small board 1x2 across the front as a foot/stabilizer, made it quiet)

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information here to give you a straight answer.  It looks like there is some control circuitry in the metal box that's attached.  I'd normally say remove that and figure out the wiring directly to the motor, but it appears that the start capacitor goes into this control box, and since that's necessary for the motor to start, you may need to keep the control box and figure it out.  I'd open the box and see if there's a schematic on the inside cover that gives any idea.

If not, then getting a schematic for your old furnace would be the first step, if that isn't available or known you can use some techniques with a multimeter to determine how the motor is wound and use that information to hook it up.  Lastly, check with the guy that made the suggestion - he should have an idea of how to hook it up to a plug.

Answer (score 0):

It is a split phase motor there will be a run capacitor some where . the wiring is white is common black is high blue is med red is low . you have to look at the sticker on motor to find out what voltage the motor is it will be either 115 or 230 volts but not both. if your just using it to move air pick the speed you want and insulate the other 2 wires so if you want high put power to white and black insulate blue and red separately and it may or may not be reversible there is usually reversing plugs on the side of motor if is reversible
hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

That look like a 1/3 hp motor, which is a 120 volt motor you got 6 wires on that motor three is for fan speed and they are black for high, blue for med.and red for low. you have a capacitor on that motor three wires are on that capacitor a brown, on one side and a yellow and white on the other side, the white wire is one side of power choose the wire speed you want and cap off the other two so that they don't touch and wire that speed to the other side.

Answer (score -2):

Just get an extension cord, cut off one end and wire the ground to the green ground lug or wire. Next, wire the red to the 'fan" side of the cap and wire the black to the hot wire (could be black or white so read the diagram)